# Open popup window if href is 'www.example.com'

Tags: jquery, popup, href

I want all anchor links with a certain href to open in a stripped popup window. I'm unable to add a class or an onclick event to the anchor tag so I need like jQuery to check if a link with that certain href has been clicked, and in that case open a stripped popup window. Anyone?

Answer (score 2):

check this

```
jQuery("a[href*=example.com]").click(function{
    // your functionality
});
```